# Using "View As" device other than active device results in layout issues

Tags: interface-builder, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

This one is best demonstrated with a [video](https://youtu.be/Z2C6DahzM2M). The layout of my view changes based on which device I "View As: " in Interface Builder. It looks like changing this setting modifies the rects in Interface Builder, and then those changes stick. Is there a better way to prevent this from happening?

(It doesn't matter which device I use. If "View As" doesn't match the device, something will appear off.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. It was a missing constraint. I was adding my view to a page view controller, but forgot to constraint the child view in the process:

```
marqueeViewController.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
marqueeViewController.containerView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
// ** This constraint was missing, and is needed to resize the child view. **
Layout.edges(parent: marqueeViewController.containerView, child: pageViewController.view)
```

The rectangle of my views were changing size as I changed the "View As:" setting in Interface Builder. And since there was no constraint to reel them back in, they stayed set at the different size.